# Java Tcp socket: how to detect on client that no more data needs to be received by server?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp

I am sending byte[] on a java socket to a C++ server. The client doesn't know how much data will be sent in advance. Is there any other way to detect on the client side that all data was sent so the socket can be disconnected without data loss on the server side? Currently I am using Thread.sleep(1000) for not disconnecting before all data has been received but is there a better way to do this?

server.cpp:

```
do{
 memset(chunk ,0 , 4096);
 n = recv(sock , chunk , 4096 , 0);
 myFile.write(chunk, n);
} while (n>0);
```

client.java

```
while(isSending){
 try {
  DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  data = getDataFromQueue();
  out.write(data,0,data.length);
  out.flush();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

//how to wait here until all data was received?

try {
  socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Well, before sending the actual data, you could send an integer telling to the client how many bytes of data the server will send. The the client reads exactly that amount of bytes and stops receiving.

Comment: This assumes that the client knows the data size in advance which is not  the case, as stated in the question.

Comment: There is normally no data loss in TCP. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP connection is full-duplex. There are two independent byte streams, one in each direction. You can close the write half of the connection , this is called *half-close*. Any data currently in the socket send buffer will be sent, followed by TCP's normal connection termination sequence. The server will read 0 bytes then in a call to `recv` what indicates shutdown from client side.

I am not a Java expert but quick googling is telling me that `shutdownOutput()` function is what you are using in Java to close sending half of the connection.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput%28%29)

Comment: This works! Although I am not sure why shutdownOutput() is necessary instead of just calling socket.stop(), since TCP should ensure that all packets are sent (as stated in other reponses). Is it possible that some java pre-socket buffer got deleted and not sent?

Comment: you can call close() on socket, it will do the thing, shutdownOutput() is less restrictive because this only tells YOU will not send more, but you can still receive

Comment: but why is not all data sent if I call socket.stop() without some sleep?

Comment: what is sock.stop? Can you please give a link?

Answer (score 0):

Close the socket on the client side after the last bytes have been sent. The client will make sure all data intended to be sent to the server is sent before the FIN-packet that closes the connection is sent. When the remote party closes the socket, an exception will be thrown at the client. This exception should, if my memory of Java sockets servers me correctly, not be thrown before the last byte has been received. See here for a basic code example: http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/javatutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Another approach is to create your own header that you send first and that contains the number of bytes that will be sent.

Comment: This will throw an exception for the client, right?

Comment: I have not worked with Java sockets in a while, but if I remember correctly, then yes. Look at the basic EchoTest-example: http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/javatutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html. However, the exception should not be thrown before the last byte is sent.

Comment: Make sure to catch the exception. Also, code samples would help to make your answer much more useful and clear.

Comment: I know, I was just preoccuped and thought I should submit the answer before running away to do something else :)

Comment: Sure, but you should get around to it. Also, links are useful, but they can break. (also the link is broken)

Comment: TCP will ensure that all data is sent before a FIN. In the case of an RST it will throw all pending data away. There is no such thing as a 'FIN/RST packet'. It is one or the other, and they have different behaviours. The data is going from client to server, not server to client. No exception will be thrown 'when the remote party cellars the socket'. An EOFException *may* be thrown when the FIN is read, depending on which read API is being used. Far too much misinformation here. -1

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to detect on the client side that all data was sent so the socket can be disconnected without data loss on the server side?

Your assumption that data will be lost if you just close the socket is incorrect. TCP will ensure that all pending data is delivered if you close the socket normally. Just close the socket. No sleep necessary.

If you want to know that the peer received all the data, shutdown the socket for output and have the peer send an application-protocol acknowledgement when it reads end-of-stream before it closes the socket. At the sender, read this acknowledgement after you do the shutdown and before you close. If you get it, all is well.

Comment: As far as I understand, recv() will return zero if the socket is disconnected, also without all bytes sent. Why else would the number of bytes received be smaller than the number of bytes sent? (in case the socket is immediately stopped on the client side.

Comment: But the socket is *not* 'immediately stopped on the client side'. recv() returns zero *after all sent data has been received.* You're making invalid assumptions again. Or are you closing your *own* socket prematurely? In which case the answer is "don't".